# can't install pip module smtpd-tls

Tags: python-3.x, smtpd

I am trying to set up a debugging server for testing email logging and I encountered an issue with smtpd module. It was not installed and I can not pip install with with cli or add the package in Pycharm ui. From my understanding of the error it thinks my python version is less than 2.7 but I have confirmed that for this venv I am in 3.7.0. I cannot view the install log because it is a temp file and whe I go to that directory there is no such file.

Any ideas?[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This is a known bug in smtpd-tls](https://github.com/tintinweb/python-smtpd-tls/issues/1).  Unless you can get the author to update the package, you cannot install smtpd-tls in Python 3.

Comment: As a beginner in python do you have a recommendation for an alternative?

Comment: @stegnerd: No.  I've never done anything with SMTP servers.